# MTA rejects mail, returns 554 error although rDNS is set

Tags: email, smtp, email-server

I have a docker-mailserver container running fine except that mails aren't delivered to GMX and web.de which are both german mail providers belonging to the same holding company.
I assume they have the same infrastructure.
Every other mail recipient I have tested accepts my emails without a flaw. Including gmail.com and aol.com
gmx.de gives me the following error:

```
refused to talk to me: 554-gmx.net (mxgmx102) Nemesis ESMTP Service not available 554-No SMTP service 554-Bad DNS PTR resource record. 554 For explanation visit https://www.gmx.net/mail/senderguidelines?ip=194.13.81.47&c=rdns)
```

I do have a rDNS record from my IP that points to `v220200546445116977.nicesrv.de`.

`v220200546445116977.nicesrv.de` has a valid A record to my IP address.
That should be enough, right?

SPF and DKIM are set up correctly, I'm getting a full 10/10 at https://www.mail-tester.com/.
I've checked multiple backlists to checker whether my IP address is on there. It is not.

I do need to point out that I am using cloudflare as my DNS provider, I do not have any proxy enabled.
I did have it enabled in the beginning, which was when I thought it might be the reason.
Apparently, it is not.

Comment: Only the ones blocking you can give you a concrete answer but if I had to guess I'd say they're blocking anything with a PTR record that looks like a dynamically assigned address (like a home user would have) as a way to enforce _Make sure your mail server has a static IP address_.

Comment: It does have a static IP address.

Comment: To quote myself:  _PTR record that looks like a dynamically assigned address_.  The key here is _looks like_.  This looks like something dynamically assigned to me.  Just like GMX and web.de, I don't know (nor do I care) that it's statically assigned.  They care that it looks like an IP address someone else could be using tomorrow due to it's generic numbering.  You can change the PTR to something that looks reputable like mail.nicesrv.de or you can contact those blocking you for an exception.  Remember, this is all a guess as this isn't GMX or web.de.

Comment: Thank you. I do however have another server, that has a similar rDNS record. E-Mails from this server are not blocked. And that's what really makes me curious.